# How to show error message with asyncValidation on a SimpleForm?

Tags: react-admin

Without async, the classic validation prop of the SimpleForm component permit to mark invalid field in red with an error message, we only need to return an object of fields errors (eg: { username: 'already exists!' })

But with asyncValidation, I've tried to get similar results, the Fetch API call is done, the error is detected, but even if I return the object of error inside the reject() / resolve() or throw() functions, nothing happen.

May be I need to manually adjust the store, but I don't known how to do it without risks.

Here is the source code:

```
const asyncValidate = async (values, dispatch, props, field) => {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {

    if (field === 'username') {
        const res = await fetch('/api/admin-v1/users/book/username', {
          method: 'PUT',
          body: JSON.stringify({ username: values.username }),
          headers: {"Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8" }
        })
        if (res.ok) return resolve()

        const err = await res.text()
        reject({ username: err })
        // resolve({ username: err })
        // throw({ username: err })
    }

    resolve({})
  })
}

export const UserCreate = (props) => (
    <Create {...props}>
        <SimpleForm asyncValidate={asyncValidate} asyncBlurFields={['username']}>
            <TextInput source="username" />
            <TextInput source="email" type="email" />
        </SimpleForm>
    </Create>
)
```

Comment: Related issue: https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/issues/2208

Answer (score -1):

Instead of returning a new Promise, If you just return the fetch request and throw the error after getting the response from within fetch request, it works as expected.

Try this:

```
const usernameValidation = (values) => {
    if (values.username) {
        return fetch( '/user?checkusername=' + values.username).then(response => {
            if (response.status === 409) {
                var err = { username: 'That username is taken' }
                throw err
            }
        })
    }
}

export const CreateUser = props => (
<Create {...props}>
        <SimpleForm asyncValidate={usernameValidation} asyncBlurFields={[ 'username' ]}>
            <TextInput source="username"  />
 </SimpleForm>
    </Create>)
```

This works the same as validate and shows the error directly on the username field. Hope this helps.